# Is it sinful to leave abusive parents?

Tags: halal-haram, parents, children, family

**Background:**

I am currently going through a very emotionally distressing moment in my life where I am unsure which path to pursue.

As a child not even out of the womb my biological father did not want me and would had rather my mum give me away. My mother refused and so he left us. My mother later married another man who was my stepdad. He has been sexually abusing me for 5 years. My mother also is extremely mentally abusive to me and will often put the fear of Allah in me with everything and pray that many bad things happen to me.

I am an extremely respectful daughter and agree incredibly with the laws in Islam about respect towards parents. I have never done anything to intentionally harm my mother or displease her and I am constantly trying to meet her demands.

CPS was told of what was happening to me and have told me that I am able to be in foster care where I will find a family that will be able to treat me well and where I will be able to be happy.

I am however unsure on whether to go or not as I do not want to stay unhappy but I also do not want to displease Allah. All I wish for is to be happy and inshallah successful in the future but I am afraid I will be punished for leaving to a happier life.

***Question:*** **Is it sinful for me to leave my parents and get adopted into foster-care?**

Comment: Hope things have improved for you?

Answer (score 3):

I grew up with parents who will make Abu Lahb and Yazid look like angels. Since the of 1, all I can remember is PAIN from these so called parents from hell. My father took everything from us by the time I was 4 and even tried to sell us for money. He lived a luxurious life while we grew up as orphans helped by others! My mother was mentally sick since the start and treated me just like this poor girl's horrible mother. You name it cursing, praying for my death, loss, pain and setting her pups to bark at me all day long. Since the age of 5, I was always left ALONE! Allah never sent anyone in my life either. However I did get love from one person no one can ever expect. GREAT HOLY PROPHET MUHAMMAD Sallallahu Alaihe Wasalam. I saw Him in a dream where He told me this huge and unbearable trial will lead me to Jennah!
Its very easy to go on about ranks of parents in Islam. I wish Islam had shed some light on the cruel horrible people who should never have been parents in the first place. The worst wound you can have in your entire life is by your own parents who treat you worse than enemies. Like this girl I tried to tolerate but let me tell you devil and satan will stay the same and its better to leave them. You complain to Allah for not helping you. You will have to help yourself. With such horrible parents from hell who are torturing your soul every second of the day, they are not worth ruining your lie. You will suffer and God Forbid become bitter and mental like them if you continue to stay with such filth. Such unjust parents can go to hell. Leave them and never ever allow them to influence your future decisions as they will try to ruin your friendships, marriage and relationships with any other person. Such parents are extremely jealous and their only aim is to make you miserable. 
This is not the first time I have heard such story and ONLY THOSE GOING THROUGH IT KNOWS WHAT IT FEELS. NOT EVERYONE IS TESTED TO THIS EXTREME AND ALLAH WILL REWARD THEM FOR THEIR PATIENCE. 
You are better off with strangers!

Comment: it's very sorrowful to have a wicked mom !!! mothers should never be cruel to their children that's sad, i had a father that beated me all the time and made me rolling on the ground with kicks and wipes, but mother had been always my recompense.